# What determines the height of this iFrame?

Tags: html, css

I just want to know how the height is computed for the iFrame ( class = "video" ) in this fiddle...

https://jsfiddle.net/zw60rc1f/1/

```css
.video {
  width: 100%;
}


/*   width: 560px;
  height: 315px; */
```

```html
<iframe
  class="video"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/azq0S0DKS50"     
  frameborder="0" 
  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"  
  allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

The width is expanding correctly:

```
.video {
  width: 100%;
}
```

But I don't understand how the height is computed.

Comment: iframe has a default widthxheight of 300x150

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: @Quentin - not sure what you are talking about.  This is a minimalist fiddle I created not a live site.  Fiddles don't "go down".  It would be about as likely as google.com going down or the earth stopped rotating.

Comment: @Kiran - where did your answer go using vh ?

Comment: @J.M. — Quote from the document I linked to "Since these are third party services and may be unavailable at any time, make sure your question can be understood without visiting these websites.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) you can read:

> height
>
> The height of the frame in CSS pixels. Default is 150.

And

> width
>
> The width of the frame in CSS pixels. Default is 300.

An iframe doesn't maitain ratio so setting `width:100%` will simply change the width and keep the default height to `150px`.

If you want to maintain ratio you can consider the common padding trick like below:

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
}
.container:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:33%;
}
iframe {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<iframe
  class="video"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/azq0S0DKS50"     
  frameborder="0" 
  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"  
  allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
</div>
```

---

The same happen with SVG

```css
svg {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<svg>
</svg>

<svg style="width:100%">
</svg>
```

But with SVG we can have a ratio by setting viewbox

```css
svg {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 4 1">
</svg>
```

---

For an accurate explanation you can refer to [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-replaced-height) where the height of replaced element is detailed.

In your case you will fall into:

> Otherwise, if 'height' has a computed value of 'auto', but none of the conditions above are met, then the used value of 'height' must be set to the height of the largest rectangle that has a 2:1 ratio, has a height not greater than 150px, and has a width not greater than the device width.

For the last SVG case we will fall into:

> Otherwise, if 'height' has a computed value of 'auto', and the element has an intrinsic ratio then the used value of 'height' is:
>
> (used width) / (intrinsic ratio)

For the width we will have the following:

> If 'height' and 'width' both have computed values of 'auto' and **the element has an intrinsic ratio** but no intrinsic height or width, then the used value of 'width' is undefined in CSS 2.1. However, it is suggested that, if the containing block's width does not itself depend on the replaced element's width, then the used value of 'width' is calculated from the constraint equation used for block-level, non-replaced elements in normal flow.<sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width)</sup>

Comment: Thanks ... had no idea that elements could have default widths and heights.

Comment: @J.M. not a lot of them, I think only SVG and iframe

Comment: @J.M. added more example and a way if you want to maintain the ratio of the video